# how to make a function with a while that doesnt stop the program

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, maui

I am making a MAUI application. I wanted to make a method that when it starts it shows me random numbers in a label and when I play it back it stops and returns the last number. but the problem is that when it starts the whole program stop because it is in the loop.

how can i make the method "Start" parallel to the program so i can stop it manually?

```
bool Counting = false;
public int Start()
{
    Counting = true;
    int n = 0;

    while (Counting)
    {
        n = random.Next(100);
    }
    return n;

}
public void Stop()
{
    Counting = false;
}
```

Comment: Make `Start` be `async void` and put an awaited async call to `Task.Delay` with a short delay, something like `await Task.Delay(10);`. The 10 is in milliseconds.

Comment: use a `Timer` to do this instead - every X ms generate a new random number until the time is stopped

Comment: @Flydog57 but how do i return the number if it is void? and where do i put the await Task.Delay(10);?

Comment: Sorry, Async int

Answer (score 2):

use a [Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=net-7.0)

```
using System.Timers;

...

public int Value { get; set; }

...

// fire every 100ms (10x per second)
Timer timer = new Timer(100);
timer.Elapsed += { Value = random.Next(100); };
timer.AutoReset = true;
timer.Enabled = true;
```

when you want to stop, call `timer.Stop();`